# Using Backbone.js with _.noConflict()

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, conflict

I'm looking to use Backbone.js with a namespaced underscore library. Does anyone know how I can tell Backbone to refer to say, `underscore` and *not* `_`

Thanks!
Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of today (version 0.5.3) Backbone isn't ready for this in it self but it can be done:

You need to put your script tags requesting `underscore.js` and `backbone.js` first/early among your `script` tags, and do your `_.noConflict()` in a script between the `underscore,backbone` scripts and the rest of the script loading. Here's a schematic version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Labbo</title>
    <script src="underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="backbone.js"></script>
    <script>
      var underscore = _.noConflict();
    </script>

    <script>
      // In it's own script tag for readability
      console.log('_ object: ', _);
      console.log('"underscore" object: ', underscore);
      var m = new Backbone.Model({});
      console.log('Dummy backbone model: ', m);
    </script>

    <!-- Load your other scripts. From here on the '_' global isn't defined -->
    <!-- any more. -->
    <!-- <script src="your_other_scripts.js"></script> -->
  </head>

  <body>
    Open Developer Tools / Firebug and check the output in the console.
  </body>
</html>
```

(Couldn't put this on jsfiddle beacuse to demo you need control over excactly where the script tags go).

Comment: Thanks man. Yah, this is absolutely not a problem. As long as you include backbone after you include underscore and jQuery and do not add noConflict() in between loading those scripts your fine.